# AutoItX Can't load library jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dll, jacob

I'm trying to run AutoItX in a Java project. I can't find any useful guide to add .dlls to my project using *IntelliJ*. I added the .jars & .dlls I need in the **File > Project Project Structure > Libraries** but I still get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Autoit\lib\jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:151)
at com.jacob.com.JacobObject.<clinit>(JacobObject.java:110)
at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:181)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding the folder containing the .dll at **Run > Debug > Add new Configuration** then I added the main class and in the VM options I added

```
-Djul.library.dir="C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Autoit\lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue by placing the DLL file in windows directory where the jar exists and by providing the same file path. I was initially facing issues with the lib folder as there were some restrictions on my workspace saved.